# PHP code for a total newbie with just enough knowledge to debug

Tags: php

I'm just logical, not a coder.
I'm also not english, so i hope you will understand me.
I have some troubles with some PHP scripts and i don't find out where's the problem.

This code is working well as a standalone. When used with another module (joomla), it returns this error.

Code :

```
        }

        // Used for styling the active article
        $item->active = $item->id == $active_article_id ? 'active' : '';
        $item->title = self::truncate($item->title, $title_limit);
        if ($show_introtext) {
            $item->introtext = JHtml::_('content.prepare', $item->introtext, '', 'mod_sj_carousel.content');
        self::getAImages($item, $params);
            $item->introtext = self::_cleanText($item->introtext);
        } else {
            $item->introtext = JHtml::_('content.prepare', $item->introtext, '', 'mod_sj_carousel.content');
        self::getAImages($item, $params);
        }
        $item->displayIntrotext = $show_introtext ? self::truncate($item->introtext, $introtext_limit) : '';
        $item->displayReadmore = $item->alternative_readmore;
    }
    return $items;
    }
}
```

Returned Error :

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method SjCarouselHelper::getAImages() in /home/abecedai/public_html/advvpm/modules/mod_sj_carousel/core/helper.php on line 159

I've no idea how and where i should define this method. I guess the problem is in the code, not fair for my PHP configuration. What is strange, is that it's working well without another joomla plugin activated (Jcomments). When Jcomments is activated, it goes wrong and crash.

I've been parsing the code, and did not found any function or declaration with similar name. Ther is definatly a conflict.

Parsing the module code where i get this error, this is the only place where i can find getAImages().

PHP ver is 5.3.25

Please consider me as a total noob in coding. I can understand what it does, but i'm not able to code myslef as i never learned how to.

Comment: So why do you call a `getAImages()` method if it doesn't exist?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the sense of this line if it doesn't exists

```
self::getAImages($item, $params);
```

Delete and run it again.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Both of you. I've found where was the bug. The coder used on a main script "getArticleImages" and in another one "getAImages". When the main page theme was loaded, this was overdrived by the correct sentence. I modified everyone for "getArticleImages", and it works now like a charm. thank you, you really helped me both !

Answer (score 0):

Look for SjCarouselHelper. There must be 2 versions of that and one is probably overwriting the other. Keep the newer version, copy it to both locations if possible.

This is just a guess of course since I can't see the whole thing - but I'm almost certain this is what happens.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Both of you. I've found where was the bug. The coder used on a main script "getArticleImages" and in another one "getAImages". When the main page theme was loaded, this was overdrived by the correct sentence. I modified everyone for "getArticleImages", and it works now like a charm. thank you, you really helped me both !

Comment: Also, you were totally right. There was not duplicate folders, but duplicate calls with mispelling constant that was not overdrived well when changing pages.

Comment: I'm glad you've found it. Now please mark the right answer(s) so that others will know what to do in such case! As I Googled around many websites suffer from the very same problem...